# Check date format in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have my string as: "12-22-2015". Its in MM-DD-YYYY format. How can I check if is has double "-" and if its in MM-DD-YYYY format.

Basically I need to check if double - is present then use

```
Message.includes(:user)
       .select('messages.*, users.name')
       .where("messages.created_at::date = ?" , Date.strptime(@query, "%m-%d-%Y"))
       .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

query else use

```
Message.includes(:user)
       .select('messages.*, users.name')
       .where("users.name ilike ? OR messages.to ilike ?" ,"%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%")
       .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

I had added

```
Message.includes(:user).select('messages.*, users.name')
       .where(
         "users.name ilike ? OR messages.to ilike ? OR messages.created_at::date = ?",
         "%#{@query}%",
         "%#{@query}%",
         Date.strptime(@query, "%m-%d-%Y")
       )
       .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

query but got error `ArgumentError: invalid date` if `@query` is not a date.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way to tell for sure if your string is in MM-DD-YYYY format.  I mean, 01-02-2016 *might* be the second of January. But it might be the first of February (and for anywhere outside the US, probably is).

You can of course check to see if it is a valid date with:

```
begin
    date = Date.strptime(@query, "%m-%d-%Y")
    #code using date goes here
rescue ArgumentError
    #code dealing with an invalid date goes here
end
```

Or even:

```
date = Date.strptime(@query, "%m-%d-%Y") rescue nil
# date is now nil if @query wasn't a valid date
```

...which is better than nothing, but which won't catch the difference between DD-MM-YYYY and MM-DD-YYYY, or of course an incorrect date that happens to look like a real one.

Comment: How can I add it in my query: @messages = Message.includes(:user).select('messages.*, users.name').where("users.name ilike ? OR messages.to ilike ? OR messages.created_at::date = ?" ,"%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%", Date.strptime(@query, "%m-%d-%Y")).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of making an obvious statement: Check if it's a date *before* you add it to your query.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  DATE_FORMAT = "%m-%d-%Y" # Somewhere at the top of your class

  scope :search, lambda do |query|
    # Construct the base conditions and variable bindings
    conditions = "user.name ILIKE :query_for_like OR messages.to ILIKE :query_for_like"
    bindings = { query_for_like: "%#{query}" }

    # Try to parse the value as a date; get `nil` otherwise
    date_query = Date.strptime(query, DATE_FORMAT) rescue nil

    # If it's a valid date, add the date condition and binding to your arguments
    if date_query
      conditions = "#{conditions} OR messages.created_at::date = :date_query"
      bindings[:date_query] = date_query
    end

    includes(:user)
      .select('messages.*, users.name')
      .where(conditions, bindings)
  end

  # ...
end
```

Then:

```
@messages = Message.search(@query).paginate(...)
```

Comment: Dear downvoter: Please take a moment to leave a comment explaining the reason for your downvote. If my answer is lacking I would appreciate the opportunity to improve it.